# Knockout.js on Android 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js to display list values, when I do not use input elements it is good but when I use input elements inside the 'foreach', it renders bad (it does not show the list and displays broken HTML elements) on Android 2.

I am initializing the view model in a script before the end body tag:

```
$(".pageId").bind('pageinit', function(){
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
});
```

I am working with jQuery Mobile also, so I tried with

```
$(".pageId").bind('pageshow',function(){ 

$("input").checkboxradio();

});
```

But I did not work on Android 2 either.

Is there a way to make the checkboxes/radio buttons/dropdows render correctly using knockout.js on Android 2?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I was able to get it to work.  You have to use the afterRender attribute of KO to then render the jQuery Mobile elements.  For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jQueryify(elements, dataObj)
    {
        $.each(elements, function(key, obj)
        {
            if($(this).is('input[type="radio"]'))
                $(obj).checkboxradio();
            else if($(this).is('select'))
                $(obj).selectmenu();
        });
    }
</script>
```

and then in the markup

```
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: collection, afterRender: jQueryify}>
    <!-- Your template goes here -->
</div>
```

I'm sure that there is a better way of doing this, but this is how I did it.  I know that you could also use the "create" event that jQuery Mobile exposes, but I haven't looked into that.

Edit:  I just found the documentation on the jQuery Mobile site that I was looking for:  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html
If you look at the "Enhancing new markup" section you'll see their recommendation for how to render the content so that it looks right.  Also, binding to the 'pageinit' event means that anything that needs creating will already be turned into the jquery mobile widget version.  If you want to bind to the content before jquery can get to it (thus making it so that the new content is rendered with the rest), you can just bind to the regular $(document).ready() function.